Prove a pair of edges cannot intersect more than once if the drawing has $\mbox{cr}(G)$ crossings
I am trying to prove that if a drawing of a graph $G$ has $\mbox{cr}(G)$ edge crossings, then any pair of edges don't intersect more than once in the drawing. Here, $\mbox{cr}(G)$ is the crossing number of $G$, i.e. the smallest number of edge crossings which can be achieved by any planar embedding of the graph.
For context, I am asking because this paper I am reading to understand Zarankiewicz's Conjecture makes this assertion without proof (a good drawing as it is defined in the paper has the property that any 2 edges don't cross more than once; on page 2 the author states that a drawing having a pair of edges which cross more than once will have more crossings than a suitable good drawing). This assertion is not entirely clear to me, because it seems that possibly we would need to cross an edge twice to bypass a cluster of edges we would have had to intersect had we not intersected this edge twice, ultimately optimizing the number of crossings. For example, if the below is a portion of a drawing of a graph, it seems it could be the case that intersecting the horizontal edge twice by the same edge, as is done, would be necessary to bypass the cluster of edges beneath the edge.

So what is a way to prove this assertion?

Where is that claim in the paper?

@Randall I edited to cite the paper; the author defines a good drawing as one in which no two edges cross more than once; on page 2 he says a graph in which two edges cross more than once will have more crossings than a suitable good drawing. Also, arc is used in the paper to denote what we denote now by edge

From the Wikipedia page Crossing number, section Definitions:

If two edges with a shared endpoint cross, the drawing can be changed locally at the crossing point, leaving the rest of the drawing unchanged, to produce a different drawing with one fewer crossing. And similarly, if two edges cross two or more times, the drawing can be changed locally at two crossing points to make a different drawing with two fewer crossings.

Here, 'to change locally' means 'to perform surgery' (i.e., replacing a crossing '$\times$' by '> <' or '$\vee$ $\wedge$') in a way which does not change the underlying graph, of course. In the case of your drawing, the left-most '+' would become a '$^{\lrcorner} \;_{\ulcorner}$', whereas the right-most '+' would become a '$_{\urcorner} \; ^{\llcorner}$': in this way, one removes two intersections in the drawing of the same graph.
So, if a drawing of $G$ realizes $cr(G)$, and if there were two edges crossing each other more than once, than one could perform a surgery as above to reduce the number of crossings, which would be a contradiction.
